# ¿Cómo mostrar un toast dentro del método onResponse de un jsonRequest?

Tags: android, android-volley

Hago una solicitud con un `jsonRequest` y quiero que conforme al dato de la respuesta se muestre un mensaje.

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        if (response.toString().contains("no encontrado")) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
} ...
```

El `Toast` nunca aparece en la pantalla.

También he probado de las siguientes formas:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Muestra un `Log` del objeto completo y dinos cómo se muestra el JSON, o sea de `response.toString()`, me parece extraño que el JSON acepte una clave con espacios en blanco: `no encontrado`... mala cosa esa. De todos modos, para leer JSON deberías abrir un bloque `try catch` para manejar posibles excepciones (errores) en el JSON. Si no lo haces, la App hará crack ante un JSON mal formado o vacío.

Comment: Por otra parte, es mejor que, si la petición te devuelve realmente un objeto JSON, uses tal objeto y sus métodos para encontrar la clave. O sea, `response` debería ser un objeto JSON, entonces puedes hacer algo así: `if (response.has("no encontrado")) { //resto del código }` en este caso se usa [el método `has`, de la clase `JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#has(java.lang.String)), que es el adecuado para saber si ese JSON tiene una clave dada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes seguir tratando tu `JSONObject` como tal, y usar el [método **`has`** de la clase `JSONObject`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#has(java.lang.String)), que es el más adecuado para determinar si un objeto JSON contiene una determinada clave:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("TEST", response.toString());  //Sólo para verificar respuesta, eliminar esta línea luego
                        if (response.has("no encontrado")) {
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
} ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Si te encuentras dentro de la Activity `LoginActivity`, es correcto como estas creando el `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

NO uses `this` como contexto dentro del listener para generar el `Toast`.

El `Toast` podría no estarse mostrando por 3 razones:

1) No tienes conexión por lo tanto no puedes realizar la petición.

2) El texto "no encontrado" no se encuentra o es diferente al especificado.

Por ejemplo si en realidad se contiene el mensaje "No Encontrado" en lugar de  "no encontrado", en realidad no encontrará el texto, para esto te sugiero usar también el método `.toLowerCase()`

```
new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
         @Override
         public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
             if (response.toString().toLowerCase().contains("no encontrado")) {
                 Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrecto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }
```

3) Ocurió un error, en este caso puedes usar `Response.ErrorListener()` y su método `onErrorResponse()` para mostrar un `Toast` indicando este problema.

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Ocurrio un error: " + volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```